# java.io.IOException: Error in HTTP operation

Tags: java-me, midlet, j2mepolish

I am from Bangalore-India. I have developed few J2ME applications that involves client/server interaction through HTTP connection. 
I am testing my application on both the leading operators of the country- Airtel and Vodafone. My Midlet works fine with S60rd edition and S40 2nd edition(6030) phone. but as soon as i switch to S40 3rd edition phones like 6233, I am not able to acces the GPRS through my MIDLET. Though the GPRS is working fine with the native phone browser.

Even the MIDLET is not able to access GPRS on currently released phones such as 5310 Xpress Music and 3110 classic.

I have done some packet captures as weel at my server end but the observation is that my request is not reaching upto the server.

I have gone through tons of web references that talk abt APN settings, but no solution has worked for me :(

Is there anyone who can help me out so solve this S40 specific problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could have something to do with signing the midlets. Is your midlet signed? Have you granted proper permissions to the midlet?

Comment: Yes,, we have signed the midlet application .....Actually in many other 
( e71,5800, 5235, 5230 etc. ) 
 mobile it is working fine....

Answer (score 0):

Can you access GPRS from any MIDlets other than yours?  If not, then it sounds very much like a GPRS settings problem.

If I remember correctly, S40 handsets have a Streaming settings option in the settings menu.  Ensure you've created a GPRS access point which is referenced in the streaming settings option.